# jquery: why i can't return boolean in function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, boolean, return

i have current code:

```
<button onclick="ismeloggedin()">
```

script:

```
function ismeloggedin(){
    if(checkloggedin()){
        alert('you"re logged in');
    }else{
        alert('you didn"t login!!!!');
    }
}

function checkloggedin(){
    $.post('/test/check/',{'loggedin':0},function(data,status){
        return (data.status == 'error')?false:true; 
    });
}
```

php is not necessary but post anyway

```
function check(){
    is(isset($_POST['loggedin'])){
        if(isLoggedIn()){
            $json = ['status'=>'success'];
        }else{
            $json = ['status'=>'error'];
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

i got the issue is `checkloggedin()` this function return `undefined`

instead return true/false

Comment: its a return for the callback, not for the `checkloggedin` function.

Comment: This is because the request is asynchronous. Handle the response in the callback function, and in general read up on how to work asynchronously/event-based in JS.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `post` function is *asynchronous*. That means that your function is returning before the data is loaded, so there is no way to get that value back to the original function.

You'll have to re-think the structure of your code, remembering that the data will not be immediately available. For example, when the page loads you could send the request, then when it completes (i.e. when your inner function is called) you can modify content on the page accordingly.

Comment: so what should i use? `$.ajax` or any other?

Comment: @jkjk $.post is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",..`

Comment: No, `ajax` is also asynchronous, as is every way of getting data from a server. If you somehow found a way to make it synchronous, it would be a terrible user experience because it would freeze the page while loading. Change your way of thinking about the data.

Comment: what method can i achieve this?

Comment: Kamil T's answer is an implementation of what I suggested. But if you really need the data at the instant the page is loaded, you have no choice but to send it with the initial HTML (via server-side scripts)

Answer (score 0):

```
function GenerateResult(pResult){
    if(pResult){
        alert('you\'re logged in');
    }else{
        alert('you didn\'t login!!!!');
    }
}

function ismeloggedin(){
    $.post('/test/check/',{'loggedin':0},function(data,status){
        GenerateResult((data.status == 'error')?false:true);
    });
}
```

Comment: but actually i need to return a value,because my script have multiple cases need to check is the user logged in

Comment: @jkjk then you must store the result in a variable and only run your code once the variable is set (which is better than making a new HTTP request god-knows-how-many-times anyway)

Comment: i put the function in external js file,how can i use variable?

Comment: @jk jk - what exactly do you mean by "how can i use variable" ?

Comment: i tried `var xx;$.post...{xx = ...};return xx;` but seems return nothing

Comment: It's the same problem as above. The ajax handler will be finished AFTER you do "return xx;". The only thing you can do is to pass the value through the asynchronous ajax handler to some other, synchronous function.